# Lua Logging libraries and open file limits

Tags: logging, nginx, lua

I am using [lua-log](https://github.com/moteus/lua-log) for some logging purpose. Itself it's a fine piece of code but in my cause, I have to call the lua script through nginx. I my code I am creating the log interface with

```
local log = require 'log'.new(
  'trace',
    require 'log.writer.list'.new(                    -- multi writers:
    require 'log.writer.file.roll'.new(               -- * roll files
      LOG_FILE_PATH,
      LOG_FILE_NAME,
      5,                                              -- count files
      4096*4096*4096                                  -- max file size in bytes
    )
  ), require 'log.formatter.concat'.new()
)
```

and later when required call the log function to log anything. The problem I started to face since I am calling a lot of instance of the script, I am reaching open file limitation. For now, I have tuned nginx by adding this entry `worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;` but I am not sure if this is the ultimate solution.

What I want to do is to only write to the log file when it is required, but the file should not be created at the start of the script. How can I do that or if there is any other good logging available for lua? Currently I log to file, but eventually I would be using log to syslog or sql.

Comment: Please, describe the way you are calling Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `log.file.writer` derectly and set `close_file=true` option. (Checkout [file.roll](https://github.com/moteus/lua-log/blob/master/lua/log/writer/file/roll.lua#L5-L15) implementation).
But there no syncronysation beetween threads/processes to access to log file. Also size of logfile to rollout count when write operation perform as `size=size+#data` and you can get file size greater than you expect.

To work with multithreaded application I use ZeroMQ writers.
You can run writer to file in separate process/thread and use inproc/ipc to sendout messages. Also you can use UDP protocol instead of ZeroMQ.

Comment: IMHO, this answer contains right answer, but it isn't properly accented. https://github.com/moteus/lua-log homepage contains some example how to "Write to file from separate thread"